# I have an error on Pytorch and in particular with nllloss

Tags: pytorch

I want to appply the criterion, where
`criterion = nn.NLLLoss()`
I apply it on output and labels

```
loss = criterion(output.view(-1,1), labels.long())
```

where:

*the shape of the labels

```
labels
tensor([ 1,  4,  1,  1,  4,  1,  2,  3,  2,  4,  2,  3,  3,  4,
         0,  4])
output
tensor([ 0.1829,  0.1959,  0.1909,  0.1895,  0.1914,  0.1883,  0.1895,
         0.1884,  0.1865,  0.1931,  0.1883,  0.1917,  0.1942,  0.1937,
         0.1897,  0.1934])
```

the shape of the output
`torch.Size([16])`

On the following line:

`loss = criterion(output.view(-1,1), labels.long())`

I get this error:

The error is:

> RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1524584710464/work/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:97

Any ideas?

Comment: how many classes do you have?

Comment: I have 5 classes.

Comment: Then why do you have 16 outputs?

Comment: Your label and output shapes must be `[batch_size]` and `[batch_size, n_classes]` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your label and output shapes must be `[batch_size]` and `[batch_size, n_classes]` respectively.